# How to set a global variable inside c# method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I tried to assign currenturl to SiteName(Global variable) but while changing to a new method SiteName(global variable) getting null.
can anyone please help?

```
public string SiteName;

public ActionResult Admin()
{
   string currentUrl = HttpContext.Request.Url.Segments.Last();

   SiteName = currentUrl;         

   return View();

}
```

Comment: Your variable is not really global, it's a public class member field. To archive your goal you could make it static: `public static string SiteName;`. I must say; you question seems to indicate you should read about classes and objects.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Thanks is expressed by upvoting and marking an answer as answer ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can define global variables, but you can have **static members**.

```
public static class MyStaticValues
{
   public static string currentUrl{get;set;}
}
```

And then you can retrieve that from anywhere in the code:

```
String SiteName = MyStaticValues.currentUrl + value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using asp: there is a [Session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.application(v=vs.110).aspx) object for this purpose:

```
public ActionResult Admin()
{
   string currentUrl = HttpContext.Request.Url.Segments.Last();

   //per session (let's say: per user)
   //you can read and write to this variable
   Session["SiteName"] = currentUrl;   

   //"global" variables: for all users
   HttpContext.Application["SiteName"] = currentUrl;

   return View();
}
```

You can retrieve it the same way throughout your application where you have access to the httpcontext.

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
   //per session (let's say: per user)
   //you can read and write to this variable
   var currentUrl = Session["SiteName"];   

   //or

   //"global" variables: for all users
   currentUrl = HttpContext.Application["SiteName"];

   return View();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To use global variables in an asp.net MVC is not a best practice.

I suggest to use Session variables instead.

```
public ActionResult MyPage(PageData pageData)
{
   Session["SiteName"] = HttpContext.Request.Url.Segments.Last();
   return View();
}
```

Than you can call it in another ActionResult

```
public ActionResult MyPage2(PageData pageData)
{
   var SiteName = Session["SiteName"].ToString();
   return View();
}
```